# Unread counts per stream/user?

Tags: getstream-io

Ive gone through your docs and searched and have not found an answer to this.  Wondering if you have a way to get how many items in a given stream have not been read by a given user?

Answer (score 1):

The `is_seen` and `is_read` flags on activities are not set per user (see [the notification feed docs](https://getstream.io/docs/#notification-feeds)). Once an activity has been marked as read/seen, it will be marked as read/seen on subsequent retrievals, regardless of user. In that sense, there is no mechanism to retrieve how many items in a given stream/feed have not been read by a specific user.

However, a common use case is to create separate notification feeds per user, e.g.
`notification:billy` and `notification:jimmy` and use [targeting](https://getstream.io/docs/#targetting) with your activities to get them on both feeds:

```
{
    "actor": "shelly",
    "verb": "like",
    "object": "state:idaho",
    "to": ["notification:billy", "notification:jimmy"]
}
```

In this way you could check how many items have not been read by `billy` via the `unread` field in the retrieval call for the `notification:billy` feed.

Comment: The targeting link is broken, should be [https://getstream.io/docs/targeting/?language=js](https://getstream.io/docs/targeting/?language=js)